# How to specify Java path with PhoneGap CLI

Tags: android, phonegap-cli

I'm trying to do a phonegap CLI build on a (Windows) machine that has multiple JDKs installed. I can get it to build when I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to a recent version of Java. I'm just doing a "phonegap build android" from the command line.

However, this machine needs to have JAVA_HOME set to a certain older version of Java in order to build other things. And the phonegap app will not build correctly with this older version. Is there anyway to tell phonegap via the commandline to ignore JAVA_HOME and use another path for it's Java dependency?

Comment: Can you not just have different users for different environment variables ?

Comment: Kind of hard, its part of a build system that doesn't allow for that easily. But If that's the only way to go, I'd have to look into it.